# How do I edit a global variable within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope, global-variables

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make a small text based game I've listed the amount of health the player has and when I try to edit the variable within a function it doesn't change the global variable and when I try to use the global command to define it as a global variable it says the parameter is already a global variable and return also doesn't work?

```
import random
health = 100
dHealth = 1000

def attack(dHealth):
    attack = random.randint(5,50)
    dHealth = dHealth - attack
    print("You dealth", attack,"damage, the dragon has", dHealth,"health left!")
   
 
attack(dHealth)
print(dHealth)
```

I wanted the variable to go from 1000 to a number between 995 to 950

Comment: I'm guessing you trie to use the `global` statement in the global scope. It needs to be in the scope where you want the name to be declared global.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to specify `inside` the function that it is the global variable you are trying to change. The code looks something like this:

```
import random
health = 100
dHealth = 1000

def attack(): # If you pass dHealth here, it only changes the local instance and not 
              # the global one
    global dHealth
    attack = random.randint(5,50)
    dHealth = dHealth - attack
    print("You dealth", attack,"damage, the dragon has", dHealth,"health left!")
   
 
attack()
print(dHealth)
```

But there is another way, and that is to return a value with the function and assign it to `dHealth`
Code:

```
import random
health = 100
dHealth = 1000

def attack(dHealth):
    attack = random.randint(5,50)
    dHealth = dHealth - attack
    print("You dealth", attack,"damage, the dragon has", dHealth,"health left!")
    return dHealth
   
 
dHealth = attack(dHealth) # Here, the returned value of dHealth after 
                          # reduction is assigned to the global variable
                          # so no need to use global variables
print(dHealth)
```

Comment: thanks that'll help a lot the one thing I was struggling with is when I tried to identify the scope inside of the function it kept telling me the parameter was already a global scope?

Comment: That is because the parameter i.e. the argument `dHealth` has the same name as the global variable i.e `dHealth`. Hence when you try to use `global dHeatlh` along with naming the local argument as `dHealth` the same name conflicts with each other.

Comment: For Example, let's say I work in a local branch of an MNC but you work in a global branch. Now, My local id is the same as your global id. So, if my branch tries to introduce you with your ID, it will be the same as mine, causing confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be *not* to use it as a global variable. `attack` should take a value and *return* the updated value.

```
import random
health = 100
dHealth = 1000

def attack(monster, health):
    attack = random.randint(5,50)
    health = health - attack
    print("You dealt", attack,"damage, the ", monster, " has", health,"health left!")
    return health
   
 
dHealth = attack("dragon", dHealth)
print(dHealth)
```

Since `attack` is, theoretically, no longer specific to the dragon's health, it takes an additional parameter to name the monster being attacked for the call to `print`.

Comment: I was just about to edit my answer to add this part, had it on my clipboard